# EXCEL Find closest zip code number where states are equal

Tags: excel, find, zipcode

sorry if this has been asked before. I have 4 columns. `Column A = TARGETZIPCODE`, `Column B = TState`, `Column G = ALLZIPCODES`, `Column H = AState`. I need to find the closest "`ALLZIPCODES`" to the "`TARGETZIPCODE`" where the state is the same.

I have been using `Vlookup(A1,$G:$H,1,TRUE)`, which grabs the closest zipcode to my target zipcode but, I need the states to be the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2010 or later you can use this INDEX() formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G$1:$G1000/(($G$1:$G1000>=A1)*($H$1:$H1000=B1)),1)
```

If you have 2007 or earlier then use the following array formula:

```
=MIN(IF((($G$1:$G1000>=A1)*($H$1:$H1000=B1)),$G$1:$G1000))
```

Or this array formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,IF($H$1:$H1000=B1,$G$1:$G1000),1,TRUE)
```

Being an array formula you must confirm it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Also since all are technically array formulas the calculations are exponential based on size of ranges, so limiting the size of the ranges will speed up the calculations.